# Is usage on objc 'iskKindOfClass:' an indication of bad design?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Is the objective-c 'isKindOfClass:'/'isMemberOfClass:' methods considered as ugly as the java 'instanceof'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective C is a highly dynamic language so using isKindOfClass/isMemberClass is sometimes necessary so no, **IMHO** it is not considered ugly, rather a feature.